# f2py with hello world

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, f2py

I am trying to learn how to compile fortran code in python using f2py. I am using Python 2.7.10 (via Python (x,y)) and Mingw32 as my compiler. I am trying to get this to work in 64-bit Windows 7, but the Python 2.7.10 is running in 32-bit. I added the appropriate paths for `C:\MingW\bin\` and the `C:\Python27\` to my system's PATH file.

When I trying to compile a simple hello.f "Hello, World!" program, I get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Tim\Desktop>f2py -c -m hello hello.f
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "hello" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.c
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'hello.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: hello
            Block: hello
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "hello"...
    Wrote C/API module "hello" to file "c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.c"
  adding 'c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Cannot build msvcr library: "msvcr90d.dll" not found
customize Mingw32CCompiler
customize Mingw32CCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
Found executable C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'hello' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr
creating c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7
compile options: '-DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -Ic:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c'
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -Ic:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.c -o c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.o
Found executable C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -Ic:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.c -o c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-Ic:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7 -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c'
gfortran.exe:f77: hello.f
C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.o c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\hello.o -Lc:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1 -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\hello.pyd
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\hellomodule.o c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o c:\users\tim~1.rue\appdata\local\temp\tmpriisfr\Release\hello.o -Lc:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1 -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\hello.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

Can someone help me sort out why this isn't compiling and help me to get this working?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984023/python-embedded-c-code-compilation-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this seems to be [a bug in Python 2.7.10](https://bugs.python.org/issue24385), with 32bit `libpython27.a` containing 64-bit objects. To fix it, either downgrade python to 2.7.9, or upgrade it to 2.7.11 (or you can follow the route from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984023/python-embedded-c-code-compilation-error) question, but depending on your experience this could be painful).